# Reading remote binary file for parsing

Tags: javascript, ajax, parsing, binary

I have a file at a remote server, it is binary and I know how to handle its bits. But I cannot download and render it as a binary string with Javascript for browser use. From what I read, this is as far as I got:

```
function loadFile() {
  $.get('binaryfile.ext', function(data) {
    new FileReader().readAsBinaryString(data);
  });
}
```

But I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'readAsBinaryString' on 'FileReader': The argument is not a Blob.
```

The file is downloading correctly, if I `document.write(data)` it prints the contents of the file as expected.

I found no working how-to or example on the web, I'm about 16 hours searching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a hundred percent sure about this, but I believe you can't get binary data with jQuery's ajax methods. Now with `html5` maybe things could have changed a bit. Anyway here's a hacky way you could do this.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'binaryfile.ext', true);

// Hack to pass bytes through unprocessed.
xhr.overrideMimeType('text/plain; charset=x-user-defined');

xhr.onreadystatechange = function(e) {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    var binStr = this.responseText;
    for (var i = 0, len = binStr.length; i < len; ++i) {
      var c = binStr.charCodeAt(i);
      //String.fromCharCode(c & 0xff);
      var byte = c & 0xff;  // byte at offset i
    }
  }
};

xhr.send();
```

You can find more information here: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/